# MPAndroidChart missing setFillDrawable(...) method

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I've added the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library to my project using the 2.2.0 version, as described in the github page for this library.
I've tried to implement a `LineDataSet` with a gradient as was implemented in the example the library also provides.

But when I try to use the `LineDataSet.setFillDrawable` method, it isn't recognized. I suspect that is because the newest changes to the library are not present in android repository for 2.2.0 version.

Does somebody know when the new version will be available?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The new `Drawable` gradient feature for `LineChart` is **not yet in a release version**. We are currently doing some testing and stabilizing. The release should be out sometime next week most likely.